# Lower bound of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Prove the following statement:
Let $1<\beta<\sqrt{2}$ be a rational number, for any non-zero vector $(a_{n-1}\,,a_{n-2}\cdots\,,a_1\,,a_0)$(where $a_i\in\{-1\,,0\,,1\}$) and any $n\geq 3$, we have $|\beta^n+a_{n-1}\beta^{n-1}+a_{n-2}\beta^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{1}\beta^{1}+a_0|\geq |\beta^n-\beta^{n-1}-\beta^{n-2}-\cdots-\beta^{1}-1|$

Comment: Hi; if you want more responses, tell us what you've tried, what you find difficult about the problem, where you came across the problem. Thanks.

Comment: $\beta^n+a_{n-1}\beta^{n-1}+a_{n-2}\beta^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{1}\beta^{1}+a_0$ cannot be 0 because $\beta$ is rational, Here $\beta$ is given

Comment: we can check when n=3, it is true.

Comment: if this statement is not true, then how can we find the lower bound of the polynomial?

Comment: I have found this result is not right, but I want to find the lower bound of this polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false for $n = 4$.

Consider the polynomial $p(x) = x^4 - x^3 - 1$ which has a root at $\sim 1.380277569097614$.

If one take a $\beta \in (1, \sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ close to this root, the statement will be broken. Let's say we take $\beta$ as $\frac43$, it is then easy to check:

$$\left|p(\frac43)\right| = \frac{17}{81} < \frac{269}{81} = \left|
\left(\frac43\right)^4 - \left(\frac43\right)^3 - \left(\frac43\right)^2 - \left(\frac43\right) -1 \right|$$

Comment: I have known that it is not right, but I only need to find the lower bound of the polynomial.

Comment: I think that the optimal bound is when the number of positive $a_n$ and negative $a_n$ are the same, therefore, they can offset each other perfectly.

Comment: the greatest lower bound is $0$. As you can see from this example, you can pick $\beta$ as close to the root as you like. Are you trying to ask: given a fixed $\beta \in (1,\sqrt{2})$, is there some formula for lower bounds of expressions of the form: $|\beta^n+a_{n-1}\beta^{n-1}+a_{n-2}\beta^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{1}\beta^{1}+a_0|$. Please update your questions for what you really want.